# Multi-indexing - accessing the last time in every day

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, indexing

New to multiindexing in Pandas. I have data that looks like this

```
Date        Time      value
2014-01-14  12:00:04   .424
            12:01:12   .342
            12:01:19   .341
            ...
            12:05:49   .23
2014-05-12  ...
            1:02:42    .23
....
```

For now, I want to access the last time for every single date and store the value in some array. I've made a multiindex like this

```
df= pd.read_csv("df.csv",index_col=0)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,infer_datetime_format=True)
df.index =        pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index.date,df.index.time],names=['Date','Time'])

df= df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
dates = df.index.get_level_values(0)
```

So I have dates saved as an array. I want to iterate through the dates but can't either get the syntax right or am accessing the values incorrectly. I've tried a for loop but can't get it to run (`for date in dates`) and can't do direct access either (`df.loc[dates[i]]` or something like that). Also the number of time variables in each date varies. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a `groupby/max` operation. More specifically, you want to group by the `Date` and aggregate the `Time`s by taking the `max`. Since aggregation can only be done over *column* values, we'll need to change the `Time` index level into a column (by using `reset_index`):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2014-01-14', '2014-01-14', '2014-01-14', '2014-01-14', '2014-05-12', '2014-05-12'], 'Time': ['12:00:04', '12:01:12', '12:01:19', '12:05:49', '01:01:59', '01:02:42'], 'value': [0.42399999999999999, 0.34200000000000003, 0.34100000000000003, 0.23000000000000001, 0.0, 0.23000000000000001]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index(['Date', 'Time'])

df = df.reset_index('Time', drop=False)
max_times = df.groupby(level=0)['Time'].max()
print(max_times)
```

yields

```
Date
2014-01-14    12:05:49
2014-05-12     1:02:42
Name: Time, dtype: object
```

---

If you wish **to select the entire row**, then you could use `idxmax` -- but there is a caveat. `idxmax` returns index labels. Therefore, the index must be *unique* for the labels to signify unique rows. Since the `Date` level is not by itself unique, to use `idxmax` we'll need to `reset_index` completely (to make an index of unique integers):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2014-01-14', '2014-01-14', '2014-01-14', '2014-01-14', '2014-05-12', '2014-05-12'], 'Time': ['12:00:04', '12:01:12', '12:01:19', '12:05:49', '01:01:59', '1:02:42'], 'value': [0.42399999999999999, 0.34200000000000003, 0.34100000000000003, 0.23000000000000001, 0.0, 0.23000000000000001]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
df = df.set_index(['Date', 'Time'])

df = df.reset_index()
idx = df.groupby(['Date'])['Time'].idxmax()
print(df.loc[idx])
```

yields

```
        Date     Time  value
3 2014-01-14 12:05:49   0.23
5 2014-05-12 01:02:42   0.23
```

---

I don't see a good way to do this while keeping the MultiIndex. 
It is easier to perform the `groupby` operation before setting the MultiIndex.
Moreover, it is probably preferable to **preserve the datetimes as one value** instead of splitting it into two parts. Note that given a datetime/period-like Series, the [`.dt` accessor](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor) gives you easy access to the `date` and the `time` as needed. Thus you can group by the `Date` without making a `Date` column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': ['2014-01-14 12:00:04', '2014-01-14 12:01:12', '2014-01-14 12:01:19', '2014-01-14 12:05:49', '2014-05-12 01:01:59', '2014-05-12 01:02:42'], 'value': [0.42399999999999999, 0.34200000000000003, 0.34100000000000003, 0.23000000000000001, 0.0, 0.23000000000000001]})
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
# df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', parse_dates=[0])

idx = df.groupby(df['DateTime'].dt.date)['DateTime'].idxmax()
result = df.loc[idx]
print(result)
```

yields

```
             DateTime  value
3 2014-01-14 12:05:49   0.23
5 2014-05-12 01:02:42   0.23
```

Comment: Keeping full datetime together has got to be the way to go. +1

Comment: After a ton of tweaking, I finally landed on a solution I really liked... then I looked at yours again and it's virtually the same. :-)

Comment: Yeah, multiindexing was the wrong way to go. I thought it'd be useful if I had immediate access to indices (which I don't), but this ended up being a lot better. Thanks so much!